# Rhino.Esb "Could not find no message owner for "

Tags: esb, rhino-tools, rhino-esb

I have some services which i want to be able to publish and subscribe to messages from.

I have a backend bus console app which has the following configuration:

```
<configSections>
<section name="castle" type="Castle.Windsor.Configuration.AppDomain.CastleSectionHandler, Castle.Windsor" />
</configSections>
<castle>
<facilities>
<facility id="rhino.esb">
<bus
                  threadCount="1"
                  numberOfRetries="5"
                  endpoint="rhino.queues://localhost:50001/SonaTribeESB_Backend"
                  name="backend"/>
<messages />
</facility>
</facilities>
```

and is fired using:

```
QueueUtil.PrepareQueue("backend");
_container = new WindsorContainer().AddFacility<WcfFacility>().Install(Configuration.FromAppConfig());
_container.Register(Component.For<IWindsorContainer>().Instance(_container));
Console.WriteLine("Backend: Starting to listen for incoming messages ...");
var host = new DefaultHost();
host.Start<BackendBootStrapper>();
Console.ReadLine();
```

I then have a WCF service which is has the following esb config:

```
<facilities>
<facility id="rhino.esb" >
<bus
                    threadCount="1"
                    numberOfRetries="5"
                    endpoint="rhino.queues://localhost:50002/SonaTribeESB_AccountClient"
                    name ="AccountClient"/>
<messages>
<add
                      name="Messages"
                      endpoint="rhino.queues://localhost:50001/SonaTribeESB_Backend" />
</messages>
</facility>
</facilities>
```

And the following in the global.asax:

```
Container.Install(Configuration.FromAppConfig());
Container.Kernel.AddFacility("rhino.esb", new RhinoServiceBusFacility());
var bus = Container.Resolve<IStartableServiceBus>();
bus.Start();
```

And then a second service with the following config:

```
<facilities>
<facility id="rhino.esb" >
<bus
                    threadCount="1"
                    numberOfRetries="5"
                    endpoint="rhino.queues://localhost:50003/SonaTribeESB_EventClient"
                    name ="EventClient"/>
<messages>
<add
                      name="Messages"
                      endpoint="rhino.queues://localhost:50001/SonaTribeESB_Backend" />
</messages>
</facility>
</facilities>
```

But whenever I try to send a message to the bus using this:

```
 _serviceBus.Send(new Esb.Messages.Account.EventAttendanceToggleMessage
                                {
                                    AccountProxy = eventAttendanceRequest.Account,
                                    EventProxy = eventAttendanceRequest.EventInstance,
                                    Attending = attending
                                });
```

I get the following error:

Could not find no message owner for SonaTribe.Esb.Messages.Account.EventAttendanceToggleMessage

Anyone got any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this was actually to do with the incorrect lifestyle being applied to the RavenDb DocumentStore in the IoC container! fixed.